# Windows DiskDrive UpperFilter sample

Tags: windows, filter, driver

I'm looking for the simplest example of Windows Driver that would be a DiskDrive upper filter.

The DiskPerf sample used to ship with the WDK, which was an example of that, however it's no longer included in the latest WDK.

I want to write a very simple driver that will:

- Mark volumes as read-only.
- Probably fail any request to them.

In the past, I wrote a simple driver based on DiskPerf that would effectively make read-only any drive mounted after the driver would be "enabled" (ie via IOCTL commands). I want to do something very similar, except this time, it'll fail reading commands too.